# What Can I Call to Filter a String Result

Tags: javascript

If I create a conditional statement like this, it works:

```
if (this.category === 'male') {
    console.log('Male');
    this.query = this.query.substr(1, 3);
}
```

But what can I use to filter not numeric positioning on the string, but actual characters? I want to evaluate "this.query", which is a string, and filter based on certain characters being included. I can't call filter on a string, so what can I use? I don't want to just evaluate it, I want to return the new result based on those series of characters being there. This is escaping me.

Comment: Not certain what expected result is? What do you mean by "not numeric positioning"?

Comment: I am using this to filter a list of results that have been produced in search. The first conditional, using substr, will re-generate those results. But I want to re-generate results based on a certain series of characters being there. I only used the substr example to see if I could get the search results to re-generate. And that worked. A user clicks on the 'male' category and the results re-generate based on the substr. But how do I do that based on, for instance, "male" being included in the string result?

Comment: What is "certain series of characters"? What should occur if series of characters do not exist in string?

Comment: In other words, if ("this.category === 'male') is active, then only string results with 'male' should be included in the results.

Comment: If `"male"` is contained within `this.query`, return only `"male"` from `this.query`? Or, return more than `"male"` from `this.query`?

Comment: Correct. That's the intended result.

Answer (score 1):

If interpret Question correctly, you can use `String.prototype.match()`

```
if (this.category === 'male') {
    console.log('Male');
    this.query = this.query.match(this.category)[0];
}
```

Comment: That would be great if I could, I will try it, thanks.

Comment: Note, you can use `RegExp` `new RegExp(this.category, "g")` as parameter to `.match()` if you want to return an array of matches.

Comment: This didn't work, unfortunately. The results didn't regenerate like they do when I use the substr conditional. Any ideas?

Comment: What is `this.query`? Can you describe "regenerate"? What does `this.query.substr(1,3)` return?

Comment: this.query is the string that's being evaluated. So when I call substr on it, all the various string results in search all re-generate based on those filtered parameters. I am trying to create the same kind of re-generation, based on an evaluation of whether a certain series of characters is present in the string. Let me know if that makes sense or not.

Comment: With your solution above, I don't get an error, but the results don't regenerate like they do when I use:

if (this.category === 'male') {
    console.log('Male');
    this.query = this.query.substr(1, 3);
}

Comment: What is the series of characters?

Comment: That's just randomly chosen to see if everything was wired up correctly. That search re-generation is of no use to me - I just wanted to see if that would cause re-generation, which it did. What I actually want to do is re-generate results based only on the keyword being present in the evaluated string.

Comment: There are three radio buttons, each one with a different category - 'male', 'female', etc. I want the results to regenerate when a user clicks on one of the category radio buttons.

Comment: If `"male"` is in `this.query`, call `this.query = this.query.substr(1,3)`?

Comment: Sorry. No. Just to clarify, the substr method had only one test purpose - to see if I could cause re-generation. Ignore it other than that.

Comment: It should be - if 'male' is in this.query, return that result, and return none that do not contain 'male'.

Comment: Are you trying to check if `this.query` contains string `"male"`?

Comment: You can still use `.match()` to achieve expected result by including `if` condition, adjusting pattern to `if (this.query.match(this.category).length) {//do stuff}`

Comment: Okay, I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: Not working, unfortunately. I am trying:

           if (this.query.match(this.category).length) {
                    return this.query;
            }

Comment: Does `this.query` contain `this.category`? Can you include `html`, `javascript` at Question? Are you `return`ing from an `EventListener`?

Comment: So I am trying to replace the conditionals using substr with matches for strings with those categories.

Comment: Right now all results come back with a category in the string - like "David James - kid". So I want to be able to re-generate results based on JUST results like this one, ones that have "kid" in the string.

Comment: You want to adjust `this.categories`?

Comment: I want to adjust this line in each conditional:

this.query = this.query.substr(0, 2);

Comment: Instead I want it to be something like --  this.query = this.query.includes('kid'); -- or something like that.

Comment: That is what `.match()` does. You want to adjust the value of `this.query` to `Boolean`?

Comment: Make sense what I'm trying to do now?

Comment: But match didn't cause re-generation like the substr did. Not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: this.query = this.query.match('kid');

This didn't work when I tried it.

Comment: `this.query = this.query.match('kid')` does not include `[0]` which is included at `javascript` at Answer. That is, bracket notation getting element at index `0` of array returned by `.match()`. `.match()` does not return a string, but an array.

Comment: Not sure. It's a string currently. And I am trying to evaluate that string, for all results, and then re-generate only with the ones containing the text that corresponds to the relevant category.

Comment: Right. True. But I did include the [0] when I tried it. And it didn't error out. And I did get the category logged to the console. But the results didn't regenerate.

Comment: What is issue with current approach? `this.query` with `.substr()` appears to return a certain result. Not sure what that result is.

Comment: No regeneration of results when I use what you suggested.

Comment: What does `console.log(this.query)` log at `console` following `this.query = this.query.substr(1,3)`?

Comment: With this code:

            else if (this.category === 'therapists') {
                console.log('Therapists here');
                this.query = this.query.substr(1, 3);
            }

I get "Therapists here" logged to the console.

Comment: But with your code:

            else if (this.category === 'kid') {
                console.log('kid here');
                this.query = this.query.match(this.category)[0];
            }

Nothing gets logged to the console.

Comment: Yes. What does `console.lo(this.query)` log at `console` following the call to `.substr()`?

Comment: Each conditional logs correctly to the console, except the one I used like you suggested. Hope that clarifies it.

Comment: What is `this.query` before call to `.substr()`?

Comment: It is the current search results.

Comment: What is the actual text?

Comment: Once those results appear, a user clicks on a radio button (as in the HTML), and the results should regenerate accordingly.

Comment: Re: the actual text, sorry, not sure what you mean.

Comment: That does not describe what `this.query` is before call to `.substr()`. What does `console.log(this.query)` log at `console` before call to `.substr()`?

Comment: Let me try and find the relevant "this.query" code. Hold on, and thanks for the help!

Comment: If I understand what you're asking, this code:
            else if (this.category === 'physicians') {
                console.log('Physicians');
                this.query = this.query.substr(0, 1);
            }

The line before substr logs 'Physicians' to the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127468/discussion-between-guest271314-and-bkd).

Comment: @guest271314 a bit late for that, eh?

Comment: @drzaus Not sure what you mean?